# Android graphical layout eclipse

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, user-interface

I've been trying to access by graphical layout on eclipse to view my xml and it's giving me this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.configuration.ConfigurationComposite.updateThemes(ConfigurationComposite.java:1491)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.configuration.ConfigurationComposite.onRenderingTargetChange(ConfigurationComposite.java:2183)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.configuration.ConfigurationComposite.access$4(ConfigurationComposite.java:2162)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.configuration.ConfigurationComposite$2.widgetSelected(ConfigurationComposite.java:443)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4128)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1457)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1480)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1270)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3974)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3613)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2696)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2660)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```

It only started recently when I restarted eclipse. And I didn't find anything on Google etc. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create the smallest possible HelloAndroid and see if you can look at the XML of the layout.  I'm guessing that your installation of Eclipse/ADT has gone wonky, and you might need to do some reinstalling.